# When unit testing AngularJS directive, urlIsSameOrigin function fails

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine, ngroute

This is my first test for an AngularJS directive, it's possible I'm missing something very basic.

When running my test suite I get an error after the $compile function got called: when it is trying to evaluate whether the [urlIsSameOrigin](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/aa268560064e5875bd471da3f7d1ebc2f9e6b3b7/src/ng/urlUtils.js#L99):

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'parsed.protocol')

**tableDirective.js directive**

https://gist.github.com/jdreimann/a5076363f1d8f3a605a0

**tableDirective.js test**

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: TableDirective', function() {

  var $rootScope,
  $compile,
  elmBody;

  beforeEach(module('wdUiCoreApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_ , _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    elmBody = angular.element(
      '<div ui-core-table><div class="panel__header"></div></div>'
    );

    $compile(elmBody)($rootScope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));    

  describe('elmBody', function () {
    it('should be an object', function() {
      expect(elmBody).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object));
    });
  });
```

**Stacktrace**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at urlIsSameOrigin (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13820:17)
    at $http (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7629:23)
    at Function.$http.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7847:18)
    at compileTemplateUrl (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6463:13)
    at applyDirectivesToNode (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6066:24)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5669:15)
    at compile (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5602:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8082/base/test/spec/directives/tableDirective.js:18:5)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3762:17)
    at workFn (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2144:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (http://localhost:8082/base/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2129:25)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8082/base/test/spec/directives/tableDirective.js:11:14)
    at jasmine.Env.describe_ (http://localhost:8082/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:884:21)
    at jasmine.Env.describe (http://localhost:8082/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:869:15)
    at describe (http://localhost:8082/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:629:27)
    at http://localhost:8082/base/test/spec/directives/tableDirective.js:3:1
```

Comment: How does that `uiCoreTable` look like ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `uiCoreTable` directive defines its template-URL, through a function that returns the value of the element's `template` attribute.

Since your test code does not specify a `template` attribute, the template-URL is undefined and an error is thrown while Angular attempts to request the template-URL from the server.
More specifically, one of the security checks of the `$http` service raises an Exception: The test that checks the `protocol` of the URL tries to access `parsed.protocol`, but `parsed` is undefined (because `templateUrl` is undefined).

---

If it's not obvious by now, in order to make the error go away you need to specify the template-URL in the `template` attribute. E.g.:

```
elmBody = angular.element('<div ui-core-table template="/path/to/template.html">...</div>');
```

<sub>If you don't want to make an actual request to the server, you can either pre-populate the `$templateCache` with some HTML (under the key `/path/to/template.html`) or train the mocked `$httpBackend` with a custom response when the request targets `/path/to/template.html`.</sub>